# SQL syntax error (to exclude account_ID with transaction code of 293 from account_ID with transaction code of 211 & 292)

Tags: sql, ms-access

> SQL syntax error (to exclude account_ID with transaction code of 293 from account_ID with transaction code of 211 & 292)

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT ACCOUNT_ID
     FROM Transaction_Data_Flexi
     WHERE TRAN_CODE = 211 OR TRAN_CODE = 292) AS trn1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT ACCOUNT_ID
     FROM Transaction_Data_Flexi
     WHERE TRAN_CODE = 293) AS trn2
WHERE 
    trn2.ACCOUNT_ID NOT IN trn1.ACCOUNT_ID
GROUP BY 
    ACCOUNT_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a condition `ON` for your join. Use `CROSS JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` if you do not intend to specify the condition.

There will be another error - for `GROUP BY` clause you will need to specify the columns you are grouping by.

```
    GROUP BY  trn1.account_id, trn2.account_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this using `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID
FROM Transaction_Data_Flexi
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID
HAVING SUM(IIF(TRAN_CODE = 211, 1, 0)) > 0 AND
       SUM(IIF(TRAN_CODE = 292, 1, 0)) > 0 AND
       SUM(IIF(TRAN_CODE = 293, 1, 0)) = 0;
```

This checks the codes for a given transaction.  The `having` conditions validate the codes.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help! Yes yours should work but i want to try to use "NOT IN" statement and i've updated the query as below. Still i'm having issue saying missing operator near the "where" statement in the middle:             SELECT trn1.ACCOUNT_ID
FROM 
(
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID
FROM Transaction_Data_Flexi
WHERE TRAN_CODE = 211 OR TRAN_CODE = 292
) AS trn1
WHERE ACCOUNT_ID NOT IN 
(
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID
FROM Transaction_Data_Flexi
WHERE TRAN_CODE = 293
) AS trn2
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the help! Yes yours should work but i want to try to use "NOT IN" statement and i've updated the query as below. Still i'm having issue saying missing operator near the "where" statement in the middle:

```
SELECT trn1.ACCOUNT_ID
FROM 
(
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID
FROM Transaction_Data_Flexi
WHERE TRAN_CODE = 211 OR TRAN_CODE = 292
) AS trn1
WHERE ACCOUNT_ID NOT IN 
(
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID
FROM Transaction_Data_Flexi
WHERE TRAN_CODE = 293
) AS trn2
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID
```

Comment: Lose the `AS trn2`. Also next time please indicate the exact error and the line that it occurs on. In some cases `IN` performs worse that `EXISTS` for example

Comment: Also note I edited your SQL and put it in as a code block

Comment: Thanks Nick. i tried that - it says " data mismatch in the criteria expression". any thoughts?

Comment: This means that you are comparing two different data types somewhere. Most likely you need to put your tran codes in quotes like this: `'211'`